# Attack at ketone vs carboxylic acid carbonyls

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Why in this the nonbonding electrons of N group does not attack C2 as I think it is more electropositive ?

Then how pyruvic acid is converted to alanine.

Comment: Firstly your numbering is the wrong way round. Carboxylic acid should have higher priority. In any case the carboxylic acid carbon is *less* electronegative (mesomeric donation of OH oxygen lone pair into C=O $\pi^*$) and this is *especially* so when you consider that with ammonia, the carboxylic acid should be mostly deprotonated.

Comment: @orthocresol then how pyruvic acid is converted to alanine

Comment: It is a process called reductive amination, look it up.

Comment: @orthocresol so here reductive amination takes place or not

Comment: Did you consider reduction to lactic acid (A) and subsequent formation of lactide (C) upon heating?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha no I mean reduction of original compound that is pyruvic acid .

Answer (score 1):

The keto group is more reactive compared to the ester group due to the mesomeric effect (+M effect) caused by the hydroxyl group in the ester functionality, as already pointed out by orthocresol. See also  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonyl_reduction. Generally:
$$
 \mathrm{acylchloride} > \mathrm{anhydride} > \mathrm{aldehyde} > \mathrm{ketone} > \mathrm{ester} \approx \mathrm{carboxyl} > \mathrm{amide}
$$

A very detailed discussion on the subject is given for example in Warren *Organic Synthesis: Strategy and Control* or in Francis A. Carey *Advanced Organic Chemistry - Part A*.

Comment: Does here reductive amination takes place or not